# Selection Disabled in ListShuttle after Using Jquery to Show ListShuttle on Radio Clicked JQuery

Tags: jquery, jsf, components, richfaces

I am using Jquery to show/hide A ListShuttle component based on the radio button value.
Although I am able to show/hide the ListShuttle component but I am not able to select any value in ListShuttle. I also explicitly specified rendered="true" but still no success. Before using JQuery there was an  with radiobutton and a  which was getting rendered on radio button clicked.

For Jquery I removed  as well as . After that I am not able to select any value in ListShuttle..

I have one more ListShuttle on the page.However for this component I have not done any modification but after using JQuery I am not able to SELECT value in this listshuttle also. This also uses  and

Code snippet is:

```
    <h:selectOneRadio id="region"  border="0" label="Region Name" value="#{Bean.Region}" required="true" styleClass="intro" onchange="showRegionShuttle()">
<f:selectItem id="india" itemValue="All" itemLabel="All" />
<f:selectItem id="region" itemValue="Region" itemLabel="Region" />
</h:selectOneRadio> 
 </rich:panel>
</h:panelGroup>
<h:panelGroup/>

<rich:message  for="region"  styleClass="error_messages" showDetail="true"/>
<h:panelGroup/> 
</h:panelGrid>   
<h:panelGrid columns="6">
 <h:outputLabel value="Name *" id="regionLabel" styleClass="intro" escape="false" rendered="true"  /> 
<rich:spacer height="30" width="20"/> 
<h:outputLabel value=" : " styleClass="intro" id="colonLabel" escape="false" rendered="true" />
<h:panelGroup>  
<rich:listShuttle id="calListShuttle" sourceValue="#{Bean.regionSourceList}"  targetValue="#{Bean.targetList}" rendered="true" var="itemsRegion" fastOrderControlsVisible="false" orderControlsVisible="false" targetRequired="true" >

<rich:column >
<h:outputLabel value="#{itemsRegion}"/>
</rich:column >                                 
</rich:listShuttle>
</h:panelGroup>    
<h:panelGroup />
<h:panelGroup />
<rich:message  for="calListShuttle"  styleClass="error_messages" showDetail="true"/>
<h:panelGroup /> 
</h:panelGrid>
</rich:layoutPanel> 
 </rich:layout>
<rich:spacer height="20" width="18"></rich:spacer>
```

and the JQuery code is

```
function showRegionShuttle()
{
    jQuery("input:radio[@name='frmOffer\\:region']").click(function() { 
        var radioValue=jQuery("input[name='frmOffer\\:region']:checked").val();
        if(radioValue=="All")
        {
            jQuery("#frmOffer\\:regionLabel,#frmOffer\\:colonLabel,#frmOffer\\:calListShuttle").hide("fast");
        }
        else
        {
         jQuery("#frmOffer\\:regionLabel,#frmOffer\\:colonLabel,#frmOffer\\:calListShuttle").show("fast");
        }   
    });
}
```

What can be possibly wrong...
Why I am not able to select a Value in ListShuttle on inclusion of JQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the JQuery script file which came with Rich Faces will solve the problem. Also when using the richFaces jquery file it is very evident that you need to use JQuery Tag else Jquery will not fire...